# Converting listener for a stream to IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

My service method takes a listener and calls it with stream of data. I am trying to convert this stream to a `IObservable<T>`. So far this is what I have done:

```
public class MessageListener : IMessageListener
{

    private readonly Subject<string> stream = new Subject<string>();

    public IObservable<string> MessageStream
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stream;
        }
    }

    public void OnMessageAdded(string message)
    {
        this.stream.OnNext(message);
    }

}

//Calling code    
public IObservable<string> GetMessage()
{
     var listener = new MessageListener();
     service.Subscribe(listener);
     listener.MessageStream.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread);
}
```

I am not sure if this is good enough. I beleive the call to `SubscribeOn` will run only the subscription code on new thread. How will I make sure OnMessageAdded is received by a new thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already spotted yourself, SubscribeOn will only control where the subscription is going to happen. However, in your code the SubscribeOn has no effect at all because it's not followed by a subscription. Remember that SubscribeOn returns an Observable to be used for the subscription. It's not that you can call "SubscribeOn" to set some global flag inside the source or something like that.

What you actually want to do is to call "ObserveOn" inside your service right before the subscription takes place. `ObserveOn` defines the thread of processing the incomming messages. Another option would be to write the `ObserveOn` directly into the MessageListener so that it looks like this:

```
public IObservable<string> MessageStream
{
    get
    {
        return this.stream.ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool).AsObservable();
    }
}
```

Another thing to be noted, in your MessageStream Property better call `this.stream.AsObservable()` instead of directly returning the subject.

Comment: I do call subcribe at ViewModel level where I call the GetMessage method and I am also doing a ObserveOnDispatcher().

Comment: Maybe you should give more information about what the service actually does. I understand it as such that the service subscribes to the MessageStream and you want the messages to be processed by another thread. And that's why you need to call ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread) inside your service. Or maybe I'm getting you completely wrong?

Comment: Its a wpf application where the message stream is displayed in a listbox. The GetMessage() method is a ServiceProxy class that calls the actual java service that streams data by calling service.Subscribe(listener). I would like to disconnect UI thread from the serviceproxy that listens to this stream. Else the UI would freeze every time some stream comes in.

Comment: I edited my answer to point out that you could also write the ObserveOn directly into the MessageStream

Comment: thanks for that. The Subject seems to die after the first stream of data. When I debugged where onNext is called isStopped internal property of Subject is true. How do I keep the subject alive. If you know this on top of your head, else I will post it as different question.

Comment: I wonder if you call the GetMessages() part multiple times? Because if you do that you are effectively creating new subjects all the time which is not what you want.